# Kotlin: None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, healthconnect

Error: None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public operator fun <T, R> DeepRecursiveFunction<TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(R)>.invoke(value: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.content.Context
import androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient
import androidx.health.connect.client.PermissionController


import androidx.health.connect.client.aggregate.AggregationResultGroupedByPeriod
import androidx.health.connect.client.request.AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest
import androidx.health.connect.client.records.StepsRecord
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import androidx.health.connect.client.time.TimeRangeFilter
import java.time.Period

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
  private val CHANNEL = "healthconnect"
  private val DATA_AGGREGATION_CHANNEL = "dataAggregation"

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
      if (call.method == "launchHealthApp") {
        launchHealthApp()
        result.success(null)
      } else {
        result.notImplemented()
      }
    }

    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, DATA_AGGREGATION_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
      if (call.method == "aggregateStepsIntoMinutes") {
        val start = call.argument<String>("start")
        val end = call.argument<String>("end")
        val average = aggregateStepsIntoMinutes(start, end)
        result.success(average)
      } else {
        result.notImplemented()
      }
    }
  }

  private fun launchHealthApp() {
    val context: Context = this 
    val intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.healthdata")

    if (intent !== null) {
      context.startActivity(intent)
    } else {
     
    }      
  }

  private fun aggregateStepsIntoMinutes(
    start: String?,
    end: String?
  ) {
    try {
     val healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient(this)
      val startTime = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 1, 0, 0)
      val endTime = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 14, 0, 0)
      

      val response = healthConnectClient.aggregateGroupByPeriod(
        
        AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest(
          metrics = setOf(StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL),
          timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime),
          timeRangeSlicer = Period.ofDays(1)
        )
      )
      for (periodResult in response) {
       
        val totalSteps = periodResult.result[StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL]
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    
    }
  }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to write some Kotliin for my flutter app in order to aggregate data from health connect and I am getting the described error. Thanks in advance for any help.